# Cumulative curves through Dates in R

Tags: r, date, vegan, cumulative-distribution-function

I am currently working on a project in which I need to know from which date it is more convinient/pertinent to do birds monitoring. In order to do so, I would like to do a cumulative curve with the cumulative number of species (y-axis) for each date (x-axis). I initially used `specaccum` function from `vegan` package as if one date was equal to one site. While this work pretty good to give an overview of the number of repetitions (or visits) I'd need on the field, it does not provide me with the information I want to know so that I know around which date it is more pertinent to go out (since temporal aspect is important in birds appearance).
I have also simply taken the number of species per date and visualise it with a `ggplot` and it gave me a pretty decent over view, but my supervisor would like a cumulative curve.

Here is a copy of a few lines of my dataframe and what I have done so far :

Data is in french
Espèce = Species

```
PDM<- data.frame(
  Espèce= c("Corneille noire", "Alouette des champs", "Pipit farlouse", "Faisan de colchide", "Faisan de colchide", "Faisan de colchide",
             "Pipit farlouse", "Pipit farlouse", "Alouette des champs", "Corneille noire", "Mésange charbonnière", "Merle noir",
             "Étourneau sansonnet", "Pipit farlouse", "Pipit farlouse", "Alouette des champs", "Pipit farlouse", "Accenteur mouchet",
             "Linotte mélodieuse", "Corneille noire", "Corbeau freux", "Alouette des champs", "Pinson des arbres", "Pipit farlouse",
             "Merle noir", "Accenteur mouchet", "Mésange bleue", "Pigeon ramier", "Pigeon colombin", "Mésange charbonnière",
             "Faisan de colchide", "Mouette rieuse", "Vanneau huppé", "Corneille noire", "Corneille noire", "Pigeon ramier",
             "Pipit farlouse"),
  Nombre= c(2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 6, 6, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 7, 8, 3, 2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5),
  Date = c("04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022",
           "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "04/01/2022",
           "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022",
           "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022",
           "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "21/01/2022"))
```

```
PDM   <- PDM %>% 
  dplyr::select(Espèce, Date,Nombre) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Espèce) %>% 
  summarize(n = sum(Nombre))

PDM$Espèce <- as.factor(PDM$Espèce)
PDM <- PDM[!(PDM$Espèce %in% c("Lièvre variable", "Blaireau d'Europe","Lièvre d'Europe","Chat domestique","Chevreuil","Hermine","Lapin")),] # I removed mammals species, as I only study birds
PDM$Espèce <- droplevels(PDM$Espèce)
PDM <- PDM[order(as.Date(PDM$Date,format = "%d/%m/%Y")),]

PDM.w <- PDM %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = "Espèce", values_from = "n",values_fill = 0)
PDM.w<- as.data.frame(PDM.w[,2:(ncol(PDM.w))])
PDM_courbe_2_ALL <- specaccum(PDM.w)
PDM_courbe_2_ALL
plot(PDM_courbe_2_ALL, col = "blue",ci.type = "poly", ci.col = "lightblue", ci.lty = 0, ylab = "Nombre of species",xlab = "Nomber of visits", main = "Accumulation curves Site1", font.sub = 4)
```

And here the ggplot :

```
PDM <- PDM %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(n_sp = length(Espèce))

ggplot(PDM_sp) + aes(x= Date, y = n_sp) +geom_point() +  geom_smooth(fill = "lightblue") + theme_classic() + ylab("Number of species")+geom_label_repel(aes(label = as.character(Date)),
                  box.padding   = 0.35, 
                  point.padding = 0.7,
                  segment.color = 'black')+ labs(title = "Number of species through time", subtitle = "Site1")
```

And here is what I am looking for :
[Red line representing what I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni3xm.png)
It seems pretty simple to do but for some reasons I have a hard time to figure out how to count the number of **new** species for each date (in order to cumulate each of those number afterwards). I would really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Hi Wonderia, welcome to SO. It will be easier to help you if you add an example of your desired output to your question. Also, they are issues with your code. For instance, you create a "Numbre" field in your df but you refer to "Nombre" in your functions. And you refer to an object called "cible" but it's not created by your code (so add that to your question too). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but since you used `vegan::specaccum`, you can use that also for adding sampling units in arbitrary order with argument `method="collector"` This should work (untested, don't even have your data):

```r
i <- order(PDM$Date)
specaccum(PDM[i, ], method = "collector") # order PDM by Date and collect
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not aware of the collector attribute. I had to put my date in order before pivoting it wider and removing date column (otherwise I had the error 'Error in colSums(x) : 'x' must be numeric') and then it worked simply with 
specaccum(PDM.w, method = "collector"). However, I would have loved to see the date in the x-axis instead of "sites". Are you aware of any technique that could do so. Additionnally the graph came out with no confidence intervals. Is that normal?

Comment: There is no way of changing the labels to dates (`"locator"` is a generic option to use any user-specified ordering, and it does not know that in your special case you want to have specific labels). However, if you bypass the standard `plot` function of `specaccum`, you can make your plots with something like `plot(Date, collected$richness)`, where `Date` is your date variable and `collected` is the result object from the `specaccum` model with `collector` method. Then you can add other graph elements, such as `xlab`, `ylab`, `type="l"` (last for lines) etc.